# Does thread is alive if Take blocks in blocking collection class (.NET)?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I am working on Blocking collection queue in my winform application.
In MSDN it is said that BlockingCollection.Take() method  call blocks if there is no elements in it.
1)Does it mean the thread will go to the waiting state of threads queue?
2)If yes, how much time does the thread can wait?
3)How a thread is signalled automatically to come to ready  state from wait state when a new element is added to collection?
4)What is the life span of the thread that is in wait state(means is it available as long as the application is running)?

Comment: 1) yes, 2) until it can take an element from the collection 3) probably using normal event objects, which means if multiple threads try to take from the same collection, only one will be awoken when an element appears, and you probably can't control which one it will be. 4) which thread? If you mean the thread that called `Take()` then the lifespan is not in any way controlled by the blocking collection, (or rather, *should not* be controlled by that)

Comment: Please try to avoid asking multiple questions at the same time. You risk getting answers that only answer a few of these, but answer different sub-questions, and thus won't easily be able to accept any of them.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen - but these are all strongly related, I see no problem here. A question should be allowed to have  (a few) parts.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> 1) Does it mean the thread will go to the waiting state of threads queue?

The thread that called `my_collection.Take()` method will be blocked, until an item is available

> 2) If yes,how much time does the thread can wait ?

`Take` method waits indefinitely. See the [source code](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/sys/system/collections/concurrent/BlockingCollection.cs,554). Once an item is available it returns the item. But if there is nothing in the collection there is no timeout and the thread will just wait. To pass a timeout, you can use an overload of `Take`.

> 3) How a thread is signalled automatically to come to ready state from wait
>   state when a new element is added to collection?

Using slim semaphore, see the [declaration of a semaphore](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/sys/system/collections/concurrent/BlockingCollection.cs,62) and [its use](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/sys/system/collections/concurrent/BlockingCollection.cs,699).

> 4) What is the life span of that thread?

It's up to you as a developer. You can block and unblock a thread as many times as you like. Once you don't need a thread, just return control from it.

Comment: Hint: you can link to a specific line by clicking on the line number and using the address then: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/sys/system/collections/concurrent/BlockingCollection.cs,554

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen awesome!

Comment: @Oleksii: Thanks for response.For question 4,it means like thread will be alive as long as my application is running .If i dont need a thread then i need to return a control .